# Treat missing value as it is in Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, data-analysis, missing-data

I have a dataset in which some variable (categorical variable and numerical variable) has missing values. Example, i have a variable "area" with numerical value which divided into two categories, "area (today)" and "area (-1 day)". If a data row categorized as "new comer" then it will have no value on "area (-1 day)". So, normal missing value handling like removal or mean not working here. Do i have to label no value on "area (-1 day)" as a category where the variable is originally numeric? Or, is there any other suggestions?

Comment: why can't area on day -1 be zero ?

Comment: cause there is possibilities a "new comer" appears with zero area (area >= 0) and it classified as a particular class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating the newcomer as a separate class makes sense, because that's how you are treating it in your dataset - you have a separate area column for it.

Otherwise you can check various other Imputation techniques to suit your use case. Regression imputation might suit your case.

HTH